# Translating a statement into a logical expression for two different domains.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am given a statement like the following:

```
Everyone in your class has a cellular phone
```

I need to represent this twice, once for a domain of `consists of the students in your class` and once for `consists of all people`

This is confusing me because it looks like the given statement is worded in a way to only work for the first domain. I believe I have the first domain down:

Let $P(x) = $ "x has a cellular phone"

$\forall x P(x)$

However then how would the second one look? I feel like since the domain is changed now, it would be the exact same thing? Or am I messing this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a predicate $C(x)$ that is interpreted as "$x$ is in your class."

Then the sentence you want is: $$\forall x (C(x) \rightarrow P(x))$$

Comment: Doing it this way would mean that it would work for both of these domains than correct? Just to make sure I understand it, that would be because now the "Everyone" part is essentially being replaced with a variable $x$?

Comment: Yes, this works in the restricted setting too. However, then $C$ is a trivial predicate, as, it applies to everything. I think it's also important to remember that there is nothing about the collection of symbols $\forall x (C(x)\rightarrow P(x))$ that makes this work, you have to insist that $C$ and $P$ are interpreted in a particular way.

Comment: I am a little confused about your last sentence regarding them having to be interpreted in a particular way. Is this done by stating the domain or are you saying something else?

Comment: Well, $C$ is just a symbol, as is $P$. They are given a particular meaning because you stipulate the meaning. There are some examples like $\forall x (Red(x) \rightarrow \neg Blue(x))$ then sometimes confuse students. That formal sentence doesn't actually mean "Red things aren't blue." Because the symbol(s) $Red(x)$ does not mean $x$ is red, it means whatever I chose $Red(x)$ to mean. Do you see?

Comment: So if I am understanding it correctly you are stressing the importance of defining what $C(x)$ and $P(x)$ are? Because $C(x)$ could be "x is a in the world" or anything else. So you are basically saying I need to make sure I am defining these before using them by doing something like: Let $C(x)$ = "x is in your class". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is important that you make the definition of all your non-logical symbols explicit, and, to remember that, just because what you write down in logic, expresses some fact given in English, doesn't mean that it *must* express that fact, because, you could change the meaning of the non-logical symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: conditionals . . .

Longer hint: it might be easier to first express "It is not the case that every student in your class has a phone."